# Share a calendar of impersonated account with all users of a domain

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a service account impersonated with the account `slave@company.tn`.
I inserted the calendar of `slave@company.tn` to the list of calendars of the `service account`.

Now I'd like to share that calendar (of the impersonated account) with all the users of the domain `company.tn`.

--> So that calendar becames in the list of calendars of each user in the domain `company.tn`

My code after create the calendar is:

```
AclRule rule = new AclRule();
        Scope scope = new Scope();
        scope.setType("domain").setValue("default");
        rule.setScope(scope).setRole("reader");

        // Insert new access rule
        AclRule createdRule = service.acl().insert("slave@company.tn", rule).execute();
        System.out.println(createdRule.getId());
```

Am I in the right way ?.
Any suggestion is appreciated. 
Big thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way, the only problem is the line

`scope.setType("domain").setValue("default");`:

### For type `domain`, the correct value for the scope would be the actual name of the domain rather than "default".

Keep in mind: The service account needs t be assigned `owner`, not `writer` in order to share the calendar with the domain.